# @Lob annotation in JPA and Oracle 12

Tags: java, oracle, osgi, eclipselink

I am using eclipse link 2.5.2 for a project of mine. My problem is the following, I have an attribute annotated as follow:

```
@Basic()
@Column(name = "myName")
@Lob
private String myName = null;
```

but auto-generated database table (in oracle 12) has a length of 4000 chars.

I have read in internet and problem looks like that JPA does not recognize the database as oracle and I tried using:

but it throws following exception:

```
Exception Description: Database platform class [org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform] not found.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-3007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform], of class [class java.lang.String], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Class].  Ensure that the class [class java.lang.Class] is
 on the CLASSPATH.  You may need to use alternate API passing in the appropriate class loader as required, or setting it on the default ConversionManager
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:766)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
```

Application I am developing is an OSGi application based on Equinox.

I have checked and org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform is defined and its bundle ("org.eclipse.persistence.oracle") is defined as a fragment of org.eclipse.persistence.core bundle.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Problem looks like an oracle one. Even if I create the database table by command line, the lob columns is restricted to 4000 chars of length.

Comment: What do you mean by command line? Using the persistence unit without the Oracle11Platform set? The Oracle11Platform class needs to be there or EclipseLink will use a generic DatabasePlatform class that doesn't have Oracle clob support.